# HTML and CSS is not working?

Tags: html, css

I am really new when it comes to web programming, specially when it comes to HTML and CSS, I was reading the Head first book by O reily and there was this example that is not working when  I run it to my web browser, I am using Google chrome and I was using a notepad++ for this code of mine, can anyone help me out here? since my CSS code doesn't seem to work

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title> Starbuzz Coffee</title>

    <style type=”text/css”>
        body {
    background-color: #d2b48c;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    border: 1px dotted gray;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <h1>StarBuzz Coffee Beverages!</h1>


        <h2>House Blend , $1.49</h2>
        <p>A smooth, mild blend of coffee from mexico,Oblivia and Guatemala</p>

        <h2>Mocha Coffee Latter , $2.96</h2>
        <p>EsPresso, Steamed milk and Chocolate chip</p>

        <h2>Capuccino , $1.07</h2>
        <p>A mixture of Espresso, steamed milk and foam</p>

        <h2>Chai Tea , $2.59</h2>
        <p> A spicy drink with black tea, spices, milk and honey</p>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Which part of the CSS doesn't work? Also, try replacing those Unicode left and right double-quotation marks with ASCII's neutral double-quotation marks in your `<style>` tag.

Comment: the style is not working when I don't know why

Comment: what rob said.  a stab in the dark: possibly the fact that the quotes around `<style type=”text/css”>` aren't proper quotes. ie `"`

Comment: You don't even really need the type attribute at all, just about every browser will still render it although your document may not validate depending on the doctype you use.  If you use the [HTML5 <!doctype html>](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-doctype) the [type attribute is optional](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#the-style-element).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I pasted your code directly into jsfiddle and the CSS was not applied to the document.  Try changing the curly quotes (`style type=”text/css”`) to regular quotes (`style type="text/css"`) and try again.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/dPdHu/

Comment: Okay :) Thanks alot, sorry for being a burden, I am new to CSS and web programming

Answer (score 0):

instead of (shift+') to get "

do not press shift and then press '+'  to get ''

Simple yet I had the exact same problem until Rob's post.